# How to zoom into a city using JMapViewer without multiple calls to `setZoom()`

Tags: java, zooming, openstreetmap, jmapviewer

I'm using [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) with [JMapViewer](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JMapViewer) and trying to zoom my map onto a street level view of central London, but I can't zoom in my map.

I have tried using code like this:

```
map().setCenter(new Point(900, 600))
map().setZoom(50);
map().setDisplayPosition(200,200, 4)
```

However, I can only zoom onto central London successfully with code like this:

```
map().setZoom(10);
map().setCenter(new Point(131000, 87150));
map().setZoom(12);
```

Why did I need to set the zoom multiple times to get the zooming to work?

Is it possible to limit the number of zoom levels? I've found [this non-Java specific method of doing so](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/13666/openlayers-limit-the-number-of-zoom-levels), but not a Java specific implementation of limiting zoom levels.

Comment: Any error or so? Does anything happen at all?

Comment: @kwoxer I modified the question. Thanks

Comment: I never used jmapviewer. If you want guys like me to have a look on it, please create a fiddle. Otherwhise it is not probably that you can any help. Thanks.

Comment: @kwoxer what is fiddle? how can i use it? could you please give me a reference I tried searching online but its not clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is site for creating content that is running all in the browser. You can add CSS, HTML and JS just in your browser. At the end you share the running version via link here on SO. There are several alternatives like JSBin this is up to you which one you choose.

Comment: but i'm trying to use openstreetmap with java for a desktop application, not using a browser

Comment: I get something similar with `BingAerialTileSource`; apparently, the Bing attribution data is not yet loaded.